# azure-mobile-apps nodes sdk, unable to make a api call

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am closely following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk) And When i try creating the api as they have done. But when i am making a call from postman, I am unable to make get request.

```
module.exports = {
    "get": function (request, response, next) {
        try{
            var query = {
                sql: 'UPDATE EmailVerification SET verified = @completed where id = @unique',
                    parameters: [
                        { name: 'completed', value: request.query.completed,
                            name: 'unique', value: request.query.unique }
                    ]
                };


        request.azureMobile.data.execute(query)
        .then(function (results) {
            console.log(results);
            response.json("Verfied successfully");
        }).catch(function (err) { console.log(err);
            response.send(err);});
        }
        catch(ex)
        {
            console.log(ex);
            response.send(ex);
        }
    }
};
```

And in the postman, I am making the call

```
https://<appname>.azurewebsites.net/api/emailtoken?completed=true&unique=4a642af0-75be-45dd-bd8d-3c91e93a8b9d
```

Any lead will be helpful.

Here is the screenshot of the output:

[image]

PS: I have updated my question with more details and changes.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I am getting unable to get"*? Which status code did you get? **4xx** or **5xx** error?

Comment: `404 not found`

Comment: @AaronChen-MSFT fyi: The api call is working when the query is "Select * from" but when i do update its not working. - May this helps.

Comment: @AaronChen-MSFT I have updated my questions. Hope that will give you more details to help me solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the following lines of code:

```
parameters: [
    { name: 'completed', value: request.query.completed,
      name: 'unique', value: request.query.unique }
]
```

to:

```
parameters: [
    { name: 'completed', value: request.query.completed },
    { name: 'unique', value: request.query.unique }
]
```

Comment: Just Perfect! You just saved my day.